# Conditional databinding to a TimeSpan?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to bind a TextBlock to a TimeSpan, but I need to format is so that if TotalMinutes is less then 60 it should show "X min" else it should show "X h".

Its it possible? That might require tom logic test in the xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use custom `IValueConverter` implementation. There are several tutorials about that, e.g. [Data Binding using `IValueConverter` in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/234337/Data-Binding-Using-IValueConverter-in-Silverlight).

Your `IValueConverter` implementation should look like that:

```cs
public class TimeSpanToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is TimeSpan))
            throw new ArgumentException("value has to be TimeSpan", "value");

        var timespan = (TimeSpan) value;

        if (timespan.TotalMinutes > 60)
            return string.Format("{0} h", timespan.Hours.ToString());
        return string.Format("{0} m", timespan.Minutes.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```